# AmCharts panEventsEnabled=false disables ChartScrollbar input on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, amcharts

I have been experimenting with the amCharts JavaScript library but ran into an issue with mobile devices.

I'm using the AmStockChart class to create a pretty nice and responsive stock chart. Everything works great except I noticed that on mobile devices the chart consumes touch input so it is impossible to scroll the page by grabbing the chart. Then I found that you can change a setting on the StockPanel to fix this by doing the following:

```
// change settings
var panelsSettings = new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
panelsSettings.panEventsEnabled = false;
chart.panelsSettings = panelsSettings;
```

This works great, except that it seems to have not only disabled touch input on the chart, but also on the ChartScrollBar beneath the StockPanel. Is it possible to keep the scrollbar touch inputs enabled, while disabling touch inputs on the chart? Otherwise, I have no way to interact with the StockChart.

Comment: I have the same issue. Wrote to their support, will write back if I hear anything from them.

Comment: AmCharts support responded that this is fixed in v 3.11.3. I am yet to test this, yet sounds reassuring.

Comment: it doesn't work in chrome for me